# cytoscape.js nodes not grabbable after adding edge with edgehandles

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using Cytoscape.js to create a web application. To enable users to add edges, I have integrated the Edgehandles extension. Everything worked perfectly for a while, but suddenly, nodes have become ungrabbable after adding an edge through Edgehandles. Initially, `node.grabbable()` returns `true`, but after adding an edge, it returns `false`. Below is the Minimal Working Example. Note that you will have to download the files. They key listener does not seem to work here. You draw a new edge with the mouse while holding `Control` or `Meta` (command key on Mac)

**Update**: The problem only appears on my Windows 10 machine, not on my macOs machine.

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: [],
    style: [
        {
            selector: 'node',
            style: {
                'label': 'data(label)'
            }
        },
        {
            selector: 'node.observed-variable',
            style: {
                'shape': 'rectangle',
            }
        },
        {
            selector: 'node.latent-variable',
            style: {
                'shape': 'ellipse',
            }
        },
        {
            selector: 'edge',
            style: {
                'width': 3,
                'line-color': '#000',
                'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
            }
        }
    ]
});


var layout = cy.layout({ name: 'grid' });

// Initialize edgehandles extension
var eh = cy.edgehandles({
    preview: false, // disables the ghost edge preview
    hoverDelay: 150, // time spend over a target node before it's considered a hover
    handleNodes: 'node', // selector/filter for whether edges can be made from a given node
    snap: true, // when enabled, the edge can be drawn by just moving close to a target node (can be confusing on compound graphs because you don't need to actually start on the node itself to start drawing)
    handleColor: '#ff0000', // bright red
    handleSize: 10, // increase the size
    canConnect: function (sourceNode, targetNode) {
        // Allow connection if it doesn't create a parallel edge
        return !cy.elements('edge[source = "' + sourceNode.id() + '"][target = "' + targetNode.id() + '"]').length;
    }
});

var nodeIdCounter = 0;
var edgeIdCounter = 0;
function addNode(nodeType, position) {
    var nodeId = 'node' + nodeIdCounter++;
    var label = 'x' + nodeIdCounter;

    // Check if position is provided, if not, use random position
    var finalPosition = position ? position : { x: Math.random() * 400 + 50, y: Math.random() * 400 + 50 };
  
    cy.add({
        group: 'nodes',
        data: { id: nodeId, label: label },
        classes: nodeType,
        position: finalPosition
    });
    
    if(nodeType !== "constant")
    var edgeId = 'edge' + edgeIdCounter++;
    cy.add({
        group: 'edges',
        data: {
            id: edgeId,
            source: nodeId,
            target: nodeId,
            label: ''
        },
        classes: 'loop free'
    });    
}

// Listen for keydown event
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Meta' || event.key === 'Control') {
        eh.enableDrawMode();
    }
});

// Listen for keyup event
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Meta' || event.key === 'Control') {
        eh.disableDrawMode();
    }
});

addNode('observed-variable');
addNode('observed-variable');
addNode('observed-variable');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your App Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.9/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles/master/cytoscape-edgehandles.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   

    
    <div id="cy" style="width: 100%; height: 80vh;"></div>
    <script src="init_simple.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```